# Help with ORA-00933: SQL Command nor properly ended

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-7, ora-00933

If I run the following SQL using Oracle's SQL Developer.

```
select payee_id, to_char(check_date,'d') as DOW,  
(cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) as DateDiff from AP_Master  
where (cmcl_bank_cleared is not null) AND ((cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) >=1)  
order by payee_address_zip, DOW, DateDiff
```

It works fine, however when I try to do it using Delphi

```
SQL.Add('select payee_id, to_char(check_date, ' + QuotedStr('d') + ') as DOW, ');
SQL.Add('(cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) as DateDiff from AP_Master ');
SQL.Add('where (cmcl_bank_cleared is not null) AND ((cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) >=:DaysParam))');
SQL.Add('order by payee_id, DOW, DateDiff;');
```

I get the "ORA-00933: SQL Command nor properly ended" error message

Comment: sorry, i posted the wrong sql at the top, anyways, you get my drift.  replace the payee_address_zip with the payee_id and its the same sql

Comment: If you posted the wrong SQL, then please fix it by editing the question. There's no reason for inaccurate questions to exist after the inaccuracies have been discovered. It just confuses people who visit this question later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the double bracket after DayParams. You don't have it in your SQL Developer SQL. To avoid you to use StackOverflow as an Oracle SQL spell checker, you could:

1. Use the SQL editor and paste the
   query text there
2. Use a string constant and assign
   it in a whole, instead of line by
   line

Answer (score 1):

Why do you insist on doing this the hard way? :)

```
const
  SQLText =   'select payee_id, to_char(check_date, ''d'') as DOW,'#13 +
              '(cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date) as DateDiff from AP_Master'#13 +
              'where (cmcl_bank_cleared is not null)'#13 +
              'AND (cmcl_bank_cleared - check_date >=:DaysParam)'#13 +
              'order by payee_id, DOW, DateDiff'#13;

begin
  MyQuery.SQL.Text := SQLText;
  MyQuery.ParamByName('DaysParam').AsInteger := SomeNumberOfDays;
  try
    MyQuery.Open;
    // Use query results
  finally
    MyQuery.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I have a utility that will allow you to select this in the IDE and copy it to the clipboard, run the utility, and then paste directly into your SQL Developer query window (or any other edit control). I also have one that does the reverse - you select any query text into the clipboard, run the utility, and then paste the code after the `const Whatever =` to make a perfectly formed Delphi string constant to use as above (in fact, I used it after cleaning up your SQL.Add statements to make sure embedded quotes were correct).

Answer (score 0):

What components are you using in Delphi for your query?

You've got a semi-colon at the end of your ORDER BY clause string which will cause this error, depending on what components you are using for the query.